# Resolver package for Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs, visual-studio-mac

I am porting my app to use the newly release Visual Studio for Mac. When I create a new Xamarin Forms solution I no longer see the option to add a package to the shared project (only to the iOS project). This means that I cannot use the XLabs.Core Resolver class to implement a custom background renderer.

When I load a solution that was previously created with Xamarin Studio for Mac the shared solution shows NuGet packages for the shared project.

How can I get the NuGet package functionality for the shared project in Visual Studio for Mac, or alternatively, how can I use the Resolver class without the XLabs.Core package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , XLab is dead ... so find another alternative if you want to be up to date.

Secondly i would not rush to VS for Mac just yet the thing is buggy and is not really that usable .

Thirdly, just xamarin studio to add nuget packages you have to go to your projects and rightclick to your "Packages" folder the search for the nuget package that you want and add it.